# Querying AWS metadata directly using Presto

Tags: amazon-s3, metadata, presto

Is it possible to access AWS s3 (and possibly other data sources) metadata in Presto without using Hive or Athena?  Did not see any specific documentation.
thank you.

Comment: you need a metastore to store/manage Presto metadata. What do you mean when you don't want to use Hive?

Comment: Presto relies on Hive Meta service for accessing metadata of  S3 and other cloud data sources. Technically it is possible to write a connector to S3 or Azure without using HMS. Not sure about the reliance on HMS for fetching metadata.